# Coercion error using purrr to generate models

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

To improve my understanding of the R libraries purrr and dplyr I am working through an example described by [Hadley Wickham](https://devhub.io/repos/hadley-purrr) using different models and data set splits. However, I run into into a coercion error when using multiple arguments e.g. using map2() and pmap():

> (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

I have simplified my software to try and pin down where I am going wrong by using the following:

```
    library(dplyr)
    library(purrr)
    library(randomForest)

    # generate a list of data frames ( using the iris data set )

    data_list <- lapply(1:10, FUN = function(x) iris)

    # generate a list of parameters:

    param_list <- as.list(seq.int(100,1000, by = 100))

    # - following works

    models <- data_list %>% map(~randomForest(Species ~., data = .))

   # - following works

    models <- seq_along(param_list) %>% 
              map(~randomForest(Species ~., data = data_list[[.]],
                                           ntree = param_list[[.]]))

    # - following has error: Error in randomForest.default(m, y, ...) : 
    #     (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

     models <- map2(data_list, param_list, 
                 ~randomForest(Species ~., data = ., ntree = .))
```

I have been struggling with this problem for a few days therefore I am probably confused with lists, data frames etc. therefore grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be ok with :

```
models <- map2(data_list, param_list, 
               ~randomForest(Species ~., data = .x, ntree = .y))
```

In `map2`, implicit args to anonymous functions on the RHS of a formula are `.x` and `.y`.

Comment: Thanks for the solution which I have implemented on map2() and it works.  Sorry for asking another related question - but when I add a third list e.g. mtry_list <- list(2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3) to the above and use pmap() it works with:  models <- pmap(list(data_list, param_list, mtry_list), ~randomForest(Species ~., data = .x, ntree = .y, mtry = .)) - why can I use "." as the third argument and not say ".z" ?

Comment: I'm intrigued and really not sure why this works (which I confirmed on my side). I saw this issue https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr/issues/203 and when in doubt, I would advise using regular anonymous function syntax.